# MySQL How to create a dynamic table with Random number

Tags: mysql, random

here is my example:

This is a table which i will create, (static)

```
Id   Image
1     a.jpg
2     b.jpg
3     c.jpg
```

Now taking the Id as foreign key I want to create a dynamic table as

```
Rid Id
1    2
2    1
3    1
4    3
5    2 
6    3
7    3
8    2
9    2
10   1
```

Note that Id is random.
How can I?

Answer (score 0):

```
/*example table*/
create table foo(id int auto_increment primary key, rnd int);
/*now insert as much as necessary*/
/*this will create one entry*/
insert into foo(rnd)
select rand() * 2 + 1;
/*you can also use a table which has more rows than you need*/
insert into foo(rnd)
select rand() * 2 + 1 from whatever_table limit 10; /*limit it to 10 entries*/
                                                    /*or whatever           */
```